# Angular unit tests TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have added this code in my component `ngOnInit`

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.auth.user.subscribe((user) => {
      this.getById(user.id);
    });
  }
```

All working fine but now my unit tests start to fail with an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

I have looked throug this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10127 but nothing really helped.

Any ideas how to fix?

that is the auth code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<User>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //...

  public login(username, password): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>('api/auth', {username: username, password: password})
    .pipe(
      tap((user: User) => this.setAccessToken(JSON.stringify(user.accessToken))),
      tap((user: User) => this.user = Observable.of(user)),
      catchError((err, caught) => {
        return Observable.of(err);
      })
    );
  }

  public logout(): void {
    this.removeAccessToken();
    location.reload(true);
  }
}
```

The unit test is looking like:

```
describe('UserComponent', () => {
  let component: UserComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
      ],
      declarations: [ UserComponent ],
      providers: [
        UserService
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: can you put the code related to auth? the problem should be there

Comment: @Ricardo just updated

Comment: By default your **user: Observable<User>** is undefined and possibly causing the error. Can you post your unit test code. Seems you are passing an actual **AuthService** instead of using a Stub or a Mock

Comment: As @GSSwain said you are probably not mocking your service on the component unit test. But we need to see the unit test code.

Comment: just added the unit test having the single test which is failing is `'should create'`